# Halide: Demosaic algorithm bug for larger images. Seems to work for 16x16 images.

Tags: c++, trace, halide, demosaicing

I'm trying to implement demosaic algorithm for Bayer filter as shown in section 2.8 (page 8) of this pdf: http://www.arl.army.mil/arlreports/2010/ARL-TR-5061.pdf. I'm stuck on trying to realize a function over an RDom. When I use a 16x16 image, the traces actually finish, but when I use a larger image like 768x1280, the trace gets stuck on:

```
Store green.0(767, 1279);
```

Following is the simplified version of my code:

```
#include "Halide.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "halide_image_io.h"

using namespace Halide;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Buffer<uint8_t> input = Tools::load_image(argv[1]);

    RDom r(2, input.width() - 4, 2, input.height() - 4);
    r.where((r.x % 2 == 0 && r.y % 2 == 0) || (r.x % 2 == 1 && r.y % 2 == 1));

    Var x("x"), y("y");

    Func g_n, w_n, g_n_est, green("green");

    g_n(x, y) = cast<float> (0);
    w_n(x, y) = cast<float> (0);
    g_n_est(x, y) = cast<float> (0);
    green(x, y) = cast<uint8_t> (0);


    printf("width: %d\n", input.width());
    printf("height: %d\n", input.height());
    printf("channels: %d\n", input.channels());

    g_n(r.x, r.y) = abs(cast<float>(input(r.x, r.y + 1) - input(r.x, r.y - 1))) + abs(cast<float>(input(r.x, r.y) - input(r.x, r.y - 2)));
    w_n(r.x, r.y) = cast<float>(1 / (1 + g_n(r.x, r.y)));
    g_n_est(r.x, r.y) = cast<float>(input(r.x, r.y - 1) + (input(r.x, r.y) - input(r.x, r.y - 2))) / 2;

    green(r.x, r.y) = cast<uint8_t>(w_n(r.x, r.y) * g_n_est(r.x, r.y));
    green.trace_stores();



    Buffer<uint8_t> temp = green.realize(input.width(), input.height());

    Tools::save_image(temp, "result.png");

}
```

Is this a bug in Halide? In this instance, the code finishes executing and saves the output image for a 16x16 input but gets stuck in the trace for larger images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a really, really inefficient schedule. Every stage each compute *O(n)* pixels in their update definitions any time they are realized (that's now big the `RDom r` is), but the stages are also each inlined into the next. As a result, every point in `green` is recursively computing a whole image of `g_n_est` and `w_n`, and then for each of their pixels it's recursively computing a whole image of `g_n`.

What you see as a stall at `green.0(767, 1023)` is actually right *after* it has finished computing the pure definition of `green(x,y) = 0` for the last pixel, at which point it starts taking forever to actually compute all of the update stages because of the *O(n^3)* work it's doing.

This is a case where getting aggressive turning on more tracing would make the problem clearer. You can turn tracing of realizations or individual stores on globally when you configure the compile: https://github.com/halide/Halide/wiki/Debugging-Tips#tracing.

For this code, scheduling the earlier stages as `compute_root` may be what you want, though you may actually want the `g_n_est` and `w_n` definitions to be simple pure functions (no `RDom`s at all) that can be fused into `green`, scheduled in blocks, etc.